# Extremely weird behavior: IE11 seems to create an invisible tab when scripts are blocked and then allowed - how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, activex, internet-explorer-11, video.js

IE at its best:

There is a USB stick with an HTML document on it. When the user opens it in IE11 and scripts are blocked, a prompt appears to allow those scripts to run.

[image]

When you click on allow, the site seems to get reloaded, but it also looks like a new tab is opened/ closed.

As soon as JS is enabled, you get redirected to an online version of the site.

Now, on the site there is a video which starts autoplaying after 10 seconds. But in IE11, a few seconds later the same video starts playing parallely so you here the sound twice.

When you check the DOM and remove the `<video>` tag (there is only 1), one video stops playing. The one that started later though keeps playing. **Even when I visit another website the video keeps playing.**

Only closing the browser stops the video.

This behaviour does not occur when I allow scripts to be executed directly.

Using video.js and jQuery.

Any ideas?

Comment: People who use IE knows this and knows how to fix it, by allow local files running script. ... as a workaround, may I suggest you detect if IE before start the video, and if, prompt user to start video. The invisible tab will be there but not bother you with running anything, so no harm in that I guess .. !?

Comment: @LGSon thats what we did in the end, but I am still curious about what is going on there..

Answer (score 0):

HTML Elements do not require JavaScript and/or ActiveX for serving their content. They are automated.

After the page is loaded and rendered as plain HTML, allowing JavaScript, will trigger DOM construction and re-render the content. However, DOM may duplicate the instance of media object and start running a parallel stream, that is, a dupe of the stream already initiated by HTML automation. !Not visible by DOM.

So, there's no new tab being opened or failing to close, it's simply an HTML Automated instance handling the initial stream.

And this will happen only when running HTML pages locally.

Finally: 
The best way of avoiding this - expected but unwanted behavior - would be to:
Set the Video Element "autoplay" property to "false".

p.s.: 
About the following issue of which you say: "As soon as JS is enabled, you get redirected to an online version of the site."

That's something no browser can or will do for you on its own. So you'll have to remove the code that is triggering the browser navigation to the online content yourself.
Good luck.